PunktSentenceTokenizer with specific language and complex abbreviations
I've tried to adapt the solution from Configure PunktSentenceTokenizer and specify language for abbreviations containing dots (e.g. "i.d.F."). Thus, I've expected the following to work:
import nltk

additional_abbreviations = ["z.B", "z.b", "ca", "dt", "i.d.F"]
sentence_tokenizer = nltk.data.load("tokenizers/punkt/german.pickle")
sentence_tokenizer._params.abbrev_types.update(additional_abbreviations)
split_sentences = sentence_tokenizer.tokenize("Das ist z.B. ein Vogel. Das ist i.d.F. vom 10. November 1902 Geschichte. Das sind ca. 2 kg.")
print(split_sentences)

But it returns (doesn't matter if I add a dot after the "F" of "i.d.F"):
['Das ist z.B. ein Vogel.', 'Das ist i.d.F.', 'vom 10. November 1902 Geschichte.', 'Das sind ca. 2 kg.']

Thus, it doesn't handle "i.d.F." as an abbreviation, but it accepts all the other additional abbreviations as such. What am I doing wrong?

Aw - stupid me... it works perfectly fine with a complete lower case abbeviation:
import nltk

additional_abbreviations = ["z.B", "z.b", "ca", "dt", "i.d.f"]
sentence_tokenizer = nltk.data.load("tokenizers/punkt/german.pickle")
sentence_tokenizer._params.abbrev_types.update(additional_abbreviations)
split_sentences = sentence_tokenizer.tokenize("Das ist z.B. ein Vogel. Das ist i.d.F. vom 10. November 1902 Geschichte. Das sind ca. 2 kg.")
print(split_sentences)

gives
['Das ist z.B. ein Vogel.', 'Das ist i.d.F. vom 10. November 1902 Geschichte.', 'Das sind ca. 2 kg.']

